# Is there a Python shortcut to circumvent need for `print()`

Tags: python, r, pycharm

In R `3 * 2` typed on the editor can be executed in the console as `[1] 6` by having the cursor on the line where the code is typed; clicking on `Run` if using RStudio, or through Ctrl + Enter. Very convenient.

New to Python, I am coming to realize the if I want to see `6`, I may need to type `print(3 * 2)`, *unless* I type the expression directly on the Python console. Or, is there a shortcut?

Incidentally, I am using Pycharm as IDE.

Comment: You can select the code you want to execute and send it to the console in PyCharm. Check out [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html)

Comment: OK. This is *the* answer... Do you necessarily have to right-click to go to `Execute selection in console`?

Comment: If I understand the PyCharm docs correctly, you can alternatively just press <Enter>.

Comment: I'm not sure this last part works, or perhaps my Console is just too clutter to see it happening... Is there a way of erasing everything in the console... clean slate...?

Comment: ...OK... It's right click -> `Clear all`... And now I can see clearly that positioning the cursor right after the line of code in the editor, and pressing Enter, does not execute the line of code. Thank you, though for the very useful first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Pycharm charm editor go to

Settings > Keymap > Other

And change the kep map for "Execute selection in console". Double click it and select "Add keyboard shortcut"

I think the default is set the Alt+Shift+E. I was also from an R background before Pycharm and was used to the shortcut of Ctrl+R to run selected code. I think Ctrl+R might be something in Pycharm because I decided a long while back to map mine to Alt+R.

Once this is done, you can highlight a section and use your new shortcut to run it in a console. You can also just have a cursor on the line and using the shortcut will run the line and move to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You need [IPython](http://ipython.org). In particular, this ability to select a section of a saved file and re-execute it with a click or keypress is the hallmark of the [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org) interface (previously known as "IPython Notebook").

Comment: True. If I use Notebook (and a `.ipynb` file) I can execute a line with `Ctrl + Enter`.